# End-To-End encryption with several recipients

Tags: encryption

WhatsApp announced to support end-to-end encryption for normal conversations and group chats.

Assuming there is no shared private key and it's real end-to-end, then when I send a 10MB video to a group with 10 friends I have to encrypt it 10x and send it 10x ? Otherwise it's not end-to-end for me, because the server must not be able to forward it.

Is that correct? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whatsapp has implemented a PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) in order to encrypt the messages. This means that the clients authenticate themselves using keys and that the servers only store the public key.

For more info about whatsapp's security check out the following whitepaper they released:

https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf

**Answer**

The answer for your question is at page 7 of the whitepaper.

> The first time a WhatsApp group member sends a message to a group:
>
> 1. The sender generates a random 32-byte *Chain Key*.
> 2. The sender generates a random Curve25519 *Signature Key* key pair.
> 3. The sender combines the 32-byte *Chain Key* and the public key from the *Signature Key* into a *Sender Key* message .
> 4. The sender individually encrypts the *Sender Key* to each member of the group, using the pairwise messaging protocol explained previously
>
> For all subsequent messages to the group:
>
> 1. The sender derives a *Message Key* from the *Chain Key*, and updates the    *Chain Key*.
> 2. The sender encrypts the message using *AES256* in CBC mode
> 3. The sender signs the ciphertext using the *Signature Key*.
> 4. The sender transmits the single ciphertext message to the server, which does server-side fan-out to all group participants.

Comment: Since the user's public keys don't appear out of thin air and are instead delivered from the whatsapp servers, we still have to trust whatsapp not to run a man-in-the-middle.

Comment: So the answer is that it is still encrypted 10 times, just not the whole data, but rather only the data encryption key (DEK).

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, I think the group is basically a shared wall ON THE SERVER with only the members having the group's symmetric encryption key to read and write on the shared wall. Group's encryption key is securely distributed to the member being added using his own public key by the member who is adding him to the group. The server never sees the group's encryption key and can't read what is being written on wall by the members as the same is encrypted.

```
class Group{
  id,
  symmetricEncryptionKey,
  members
}
```

```
class User{
   privateKey,
   publicKey

   Group createGroup(){
     new Group(secureId(), symmetricKey(), [this])
   }

   addUserToGroup(group : Group, friend){
     friend.send(encrypt(friend.publicKey(),JoinGroupRequest(group)))
   }

   joinGroup(group: Group){
     saveToJoined(group) //symmetric key in particular to read the messages sent to group
   }

   sendMessage(groupId, message){
     send(encrypt(encryptionKeyOf(groupId), message));
   }

   receiveMessage(groupId, encryptedMessage){
     decrypt(encryptionKeyOf(groupId), encryptedMessage)
   }
}
```